# How to make pdfwrite immediately flush its output to disk from within the PS interpretter

Tags: ghostscript

I am driving the GhostScript PS interpreter interactively as a long-running process.

Within a single PostScript job I am frequently invoking the pdfwrite driver (amongst other drivers) to generate PDF files, for example as follows:

```
% ... Prior to this, do some things with the bbox and png16m driver.

<<
  /OutputDevice /pdfwrite
  /PageSize [100 100]
  /OutputFile (output.pdf)
>> setpagedevice

0 0 moveto
100 100 rlineto
stroke
0 100 moveto
100 -100 rlineto
stroke
showpage

% Now, outside of the API, do something with the generated PDF file.
```

At this point, within the application that is driving GhostScript I want to transmit the `output.pdf` file to another system. However, at this time the pdfwrite driver is yet to flush and close the file.

One way that I have found to cause pdfwrite to flush and close the file is to open a new dummy file, e.g.:

```
<< /OutputDevice /pdfwrite /OutputFile (flush.pdf) >> setpagedevice
```

However, I must then later take care of unlinking the eventually-closed dummy file.

Is there a better idiom from within the PS interpreter for causing pdfwrite to flush and close the output stream, without exiting the job loop?

**Edit**

The following does not cause the file to be flushed and closed:

```
% ... Output device is something other than pdfwrite.

save
<< /OutputDevice /pdfwrite ... >> setpagedevice

...
showpage

restore
```

Comment: If you execute a PostScript save and restore around the selection of the pdfwrite device, then that will close the device on 'restore'. The pdfwrite device only completes the output PDF file when it is closed in order that you can send multiple input files to the same output file. What you are doing with the change in OutputFile is actually closing the device and re-opening it.

Comment: Thank @KenS. That was my first thought, but it doesn't seem to work. I've edited the original question so that you can see whether I've understood what you are recommending.

Comment: Hmm that ought to work but I'm not in a position to try it right at the moment. Of course, it does depend on the current output device not being pdfwrite at the time you do a save!

Comment: Indeed, it isn't. Thanks and no pressure - this as an optimisation only.

Comment: Turns out that I'm both wrong and right. When the restore is executed the device is no longer pointed to by anything, but it is not explicitly closed. In fact it is only closed when a garbage collection mark-and-sweep detects it as being unused. So basically you are correct, there is no way to force the pdfwrite device to close it's output file except the method you are already using.